# How do I post a video response on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I **know** this feature still exists, why can't I find it after the redesign?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Watch the video at its **own page** (should include `youtube.com/watch` eg. `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwINBN0DHug` in URL). If you are watching it on a channel, click "View comments, related videos, and more" beneath the video.
2. Click inside the comment textbox directly below the thumbs up/down buttons. (says "Respond to this video." inside it when you first visit.
3. Click the "attach a video" link to the right of the comment box. The page URL should include `youtube.com/video_response_upload` eg. `http://www.youtube.com/video_response_upload?v=rEhWckYe3iQ`
4. Choose from "Record a video", "Choose a video", and "upload a video" in the grey bar and follow the instructions in the box below. When posted, your video response will appear in the "Video responses" section under the video.

Answer (score 1):

Act like you are going to add a comment to the video and then click the attach a video button to the right of the comment text area.
[image]